# Dismiss an UIKit View and back to a SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, uikit

I'm working with the Pixel SDK on SwiftUI, but the SDK is written for UIKit. I managed to display the view I need by wrapping it with MakeUIViewController, but now I need to return to the SwiftUI View by passing a value of type UIImage.

I tried to use UIHostingController but as I continue to the next SwiftUI views, it wraps them in the same UIHostingController inside the previous view, and the new view seems to be displayed inside the previous view

```
class editorDelegate : imgExported, EditControllerDelegate {

func editController(_ editController: EditController, didLoadEditing session: Session) {
    // Called after the EditController's view did load.
}

func editController(_ editController: EditController, didFinishEditing session: Session) {
 
    if let image = session.image {
        ImageExporter.shared.export(image: image, completion: { (error, uiImage) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to export image: \(error)")
                return
            }

            let exportView = UIHostingController(rootView: ExportView(imgText: .constant(image.exportedImageURL.absoluteString), uimage: .constant(uiImage!)).environmentObject(imgExported()))
            
            editController.navigationController?.pushViewController(exportView, animated: true)
            
            session.destroy()
            
        })
    }
}

    func editController(_ editController: EditController, didCancelEditing session: Session?) {
    // Called when the back button in the EditController is pressed.
    }
}


let deLegate = editorDelegate()
let container = ContainerController()

struct showFullEditor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UINavigationController
    var controllers: [UIViewController] = []

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
    
        container.editControllerDelegate = deLegate
        let sFullEditor = UINavigationController(rootViewController: container)
        sFullEditor.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
    
        return sFullEditor
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Self.Context) {
    
    }
    }
```

And this is the ExportView.Swift

```
struct ExportView: View {

@Binding var imgText: String
@Binding var uimage: UIImage

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: uimage).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MainMenuView()){
                    Text("Guardar")
                }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded(){
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uimage, nil, nil, nil)
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: MakeUpView()){
                    Text("Make Up")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: FullEditorView()){
                    Text("Borrar")
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Exported View")
    }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}
}


struct ExportView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExportView(imgText: .constant("Test"), uimage: .constant(UIImage()))
    }
}
```

And some Screens

[Here I call the SDK View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCBSt.png)

[Here I call my ExportView with the UIHostingController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDQSx.png)

[Here I press the "Guardar" Button to go to the MainMenuView, but is loading inside de UIHostingController and overlay the content inside the last view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiitj.png)

[After repeating the action several times, it occupies the entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSXkk.png)

I need to return to the "native" SwiftUI view when calling my ExportView.

Help Please!

Comment: Where is your SDK view? Which line did you call ExportView()? And where did you call ExportView()? inside of what view?

Comment: SDK view is in the SDK Package.

/*
Calling ExportView() here: 

let exportView = UIHostingController(rootView: ExportView(imgText: .constant(image.exportedImageURL.absoluteString), uimage: .constant(uiImage!)).environmentObject(imgExported()))
            
editController.navigationController?.pushViewController(exportView, animated: true)

*/
   ExportView() is called inside the UIHostingController

and ExportView() calls other views, the problem is that these other views are displayed visually inside the previous view

As can be seen in the screenshots